# How to make col-md-* work the way I want on mobile screens?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

col-md-* class in bootstrap does what I need at desktop sizes, but in mobile the responsiveness does not do what I want.

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.4s">
                    <div class="team-thumb">
                        <div class="image-holder">
                        <img src="images/test1.jpg" class="img-responsive img-circle">
                        </div>
                        <!--some stuff here-->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-2 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.4s">
                    <div class="team-thumb">
                        <div class="image-holder">
                            <img src="images/test1.jpg" class="img-responsive img-circle">
                        </div>
                        <!--some stuff here-->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Here is a link to the page: https://fossiitmandi.github.io/

Comment: What are you expecting?

Comment: Your question is vague.  What is wrong with the `col-md-*` alignment? It's doing what I would expect on mobile view.....

Comment: By the way "does not work" is a completely useless phrase.  Be specific.  What do you expect? What is it doing now that you do / don't want? etc.

Comment: I updated the question with page link, members section is not working the way I want it to.

Comment: `col-md` is not for mobile. Use `col-xs` and `col-sm`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the column breakpoints meant for smaller screens? 'md' describes the breakpoints for medium size screens. You can use 'sm' or 'xs' for smaller screens (I think 'xs' might be newer versions though). You can set col-md-4 and col-sm-6 as classes on the same element to describe how it should behave.

I'm sure a more experienced person can set you right with more details if those don't do what you want.

Comment: To offer clarity on one point; the `-xs` breakpoint exists in Bootstrap v3.x but was removed in v4.x as you just use `.col-*` (ex. `.col-3 instead of .col-xs-3`)

Comment: It does not work for me. hovering on the the divs mess them up in sm view